# Active class not working in nested routes

Tags: ember.js

In my application.hbs file I have an application wide nav bar.

```
<div class="row nav">
<div class="large-12 colummns">
    <ul class="inline-list top-nav">
            <li><h6>{{#linkTo "about.philosophy"}}ABOUT{{/linkTo}}</h6></li>
            <li><h6>//</h6></li>
            <li><h6>CONDITIONS</h6></li>
            <li><h6>//</h6></li>
            <li><h6>PROGRAMS</h6><li>
            <li><h6>//</h6></li>
            <li><h6>TESTIMONIALS</h6></li>
   </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row subnav">
    <div class="large-12 colummns">
      {{#if renderAboutSubNav}}
        {{render 'about/subnav'}}
      {{/if}}
  </div>
</div>
{{outlet}}
```

subnav.hbs:

```
<ul class="inline-list subnav-list">
  <li class="subnav-item">{{#linkTo "about.philosophy"}}philosophy{{/linkTo}}</li>
  <li class="subnav-item">//</li>   
  <li class="subnav-item">{{#linkTo "about.leadership"}}leadership{{/linkTo}}</li>
  <li class="subnav-item">//</li> 
  <li class="subnav-item">staff</li>
</ul>
```

The ABOUT link, when clicked, displays a subnav -- displayed whenever the url contains 'about'. In that subnav are about subpages -- philosophy, leadership, staff. Philosophy is actually the index page of the about section, which is why I am linking ABOUT to about.philosophy:

```
{{#linkTo "about.philosophy"}}ABOUT{{/linkTo}}
```

When I click ABOUT, the ember app renders /about/philosophy as it is supposed to, and the ABOUT link and philosophy link in the subnav are set to active.

However, when I click 'Leadership' the leadership link on the subnav is active but not the ABOUT link in the main nav, even though the url reads /about/leadership.

I don't understand why it is doing this.

My router looks like this:

```
Ew.Router.reopen(location: 'history')

Ew.Router.map ->
@.resource "about", ->
    @.route "philosophy"
    @.route "leadership"
    @.resource "staff"
@.route "conditions"
@.route "programs"
@.route "testimonials"
```

about.hbs:

```
<div class="row about-bg">
<div class="large-12 columns">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="about-phil">Eskridge & White</h1>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row philosophy-content">
<div class="large-9 columns about-us">
{{outlet}}
</div>
</div>
<div class="large-3 columns sidebar">
    {{partial 'sidebar'}}
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is you are linking to `about.philosophy`, so when you navigate to `about.leadership` active class won't be applied.

So make your `link-to` to point `about` route,
`{{#link-to "about"}}ABOUT{{/link-to}}`

And from your `about.index` route, redirect to `about.philosophy` route,
so that active class will be always applied to `about`'s `link-to` whenever you are in the child of `about` route.

A [bin](http://jsbin.com/epodAwU/11/edit) for your case.